# Shared CSS box-shadow for two HTML elements

Tags: html, css

I have a list of HTML element pairs, and each pair should have a uniform box-shadow. Normally you would do this by attaching the box-shadow style to list-item class, and everything would work just fine.

However, in my case the HTML is auto-generated, which means that

1. I cannot add any new HTML elements that could be used as a wrapper/container
2. list-item class has padding by default and it must have that padding

I've tried adding different box-shadow values to upper and lower CSS classes, but I can't seem to achieve a result that would look like the shadow is evenly around list-item and there are no shadows between upper and lower.

Here's the HTML:

```html
<div id="list">
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="upper"></div>
    <div class="lower"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <div class="upper"></div>
    <div class="lower"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, how do I achieve a box-shadow that looks like it is evenly around list-item without touching the padding property of list-item class and without adding or removing any HTML elements?

Edit - Here's a fiddle with all of the auto-generated CSS and my box-shadow attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/1snLfok3/1/

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] that at least includes those paddings etc. that you are talking about.

Comment: You want no boxshadow between bottom border of first and top border of second `.list-item`?

Comment: please show your current css otherwise this just looks like a do my code for me question and SO is not a free programming service

Comment: Idea: Use a pseudo element on `.list-item`, that you position absolute, and behind the child elements. Set top/bottom/left/right so that they match the element’s padding on the respective sides - then you should have something, that covers the same space as your two child elements. Apply box-shadow to that pseudo element then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide some CSS to clarify the issue, but here's my guess and a possible solution via :after pseudo-element

```
:root {
    --padding-size: 10px;
    --double-padding-size: 20px;
}

#list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.list-item {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: var(--padding-size);
}

.list-item:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: var(--padding-size);
    left: var(--padding-size);
    width: calc(100% - var(--double-padding-size));
    height: calc(100% - var(--double-padding-size));
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    content: "";
}

.upper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: red;
}

.lower {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: darkred;
}
```